# Is it possible to default-initialize a temporary variable?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider this code:

```
struct S { int m; };

S trick() { S s; return s; } 

void bar(S s) { /* observe s.m */ }

void foo()
{
    S s;           // s.m is indeterminate
    S* p = new S;  // p->m is indeterminate
    bar(S());      // bar() will observe S::m to be 0
    bar(trick());  // bar() will observe S::m to be indeterminate
}
```

Is it possible to construct a temporary variable of type S without resorting to tricks?

*Why do I need this?*

As I understand "default initialization" is conceptually the cheapest way to construct an object. Ability to construct a temporary in such way can be useful to ignore data you don't need with as little of overhead as possible:

```
struct S { int m; };

void foo(S* pOut);   // 3rd party function that insists on returning some data

template<class T> T* tmp_addr(T&& v) { return &v; }  // careful with this one...

foo( tmp_addr(trick()) ); // receive and discard data without zeroing out memory
```

Comment: Leaving uninitialized is cheaper than default initialization.

Comment: @Ayxan Default initialisation is the only way to leave something uninitialised. Unless by "leaving uninitialised",  you mean not create an object in the first place.

Comment: @eerorika I mean the difference between `S s{};` and `S s;`.

Comment: @Axyan Former is value initialisation. Latter is default initialisation.

Comment: Surely you mean `/* assign s.m */`, as in the case of `foo`?  *Observing* it (other than as bytes) would be undefined even if `trick()` were not already so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can default initialize a sub-object of a temporary variable.

```
template<typename T>
class default_init_tmp final {
  T t;
  public:
  default_init_tmp () /*Intentionally left blank*/ {}
  default_init_tmp (default_init_tmp const&) = delete;
  void operator=(default_init_tmp const&) = delete;
  T* operator&() { return &t; }
};
```

Granted, usually it's ill-advised to overload `operator&`, but it somehow seems appropriate here, given the general nature of the exercise. You'd use it as follows

```
int main() 
{ 
    foo(&default_init_tmp<S>()); 
}
```

Comment: Smth like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/hrheE8) maybe? With modern compilers it works fine in all cases except the one where function takes `S` by value. Hmm... note how MSVC struggles to optimize all this

Comment: Hmm... I know on my compilers (gcc & msvc) NRVO works (and even if it doesn't -- copying indeterminate value is harmless). So, in light of msvc's inability to properly optimize all use cases -- `trick()` [approach](https://godbolt.org/z/eKohbx) (even though it is more verbose) seem to be better... I wish language had a construct for default-initialized temporary :-/

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo 
{
  int i;
};

auto trick() { 
    return std::make_unique_for_overwrite <Foo>(); // C++20
    // return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);       // pre C++20
}

void foo(Foo* f);

int main() 
{ 
    foo(trick().get()); 
}
```

Comment: you must be kidding... :)

Comment: You would need to use `make_unique_for_overwrite` to get default initialisation ;)

Comment: @C.M. I am not sure what the question is quite honestly. I thought you wanted to avoid naming the variable, and here you go. A temporary that you can take address of

Comment: You should read up on [default-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) :)

Comment: @C.M. better now?

Comment: If you are gonna use `make_unique_for_overwrite` it will need to be `make_unique_for_overwrite<Foo[1]>`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica why?

Comment: As the specification says, it's only valid when `T` is an array of a known bound

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) says *"This overload only participates in overload resolution if T is not an array type."*

Comment: Appears I misread. That overload is deleted anyway. Oh welp

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to default-initialize a temporary variable?

I don't think so.

Also, the behaviour of your program is undefined, because it reads (copies) indeterminate values. A simple, and correct way to use `foo` without value initialisation is to not use a temporary:

```
S s;
foo(&s);
```

Comment: To my knowledge code in posting does not have UB. But this is beside the point -- point was to avoid using solution you proposed in favor of smth more compact (one-liner), with shorter lifetime (temporary) and without introducing a new name (hence, temporary). Plus, temporary plays better in situations like this: `if (cnd1 && foo(...)) ...` -- this code is more readable than `if(cnd1) { S s; if (foo(&s)) ...; }`. Add more conditions into this for more effect.

Comment: @C.M. `To my knowledge code in posting does not have UB.` To my knowledge, your knowledge is wrong. `temporary plays better` Feel free to use a temporary if you want. My point is that a temporary cannot be default initialised, and that your attempted trick is UB.

Comment: `UB` -- my position is "as long as we don't read S::m -- there is no UB". `temporary cannot be default initialised` -- it certainly can be (see `trick()` function in original post). I hoped there is a language construct that would allow me to achieve same thing (and wouldn't require `S` to be move-/copy-able).

Comment: @C.M. "`as long as we don't read S::m`" You read the entire object when you return a copy of it. The object contains the indeterminate member. "`It certainly can be`" There is no temporary object in `trick`, so that is not an example of default initialising a temporary object. You default initialised a named variable. "`I hoped there is a language construct that would allow me to achieve same thing (and wouldn't require S to be move-/copy-able)`" My answer is that there isn't such language construct. But not requiring S to be move/copyable is achievable by not using a temporary.

Comment: `You read the entire object when you return a copy of it` -- conceptually, yes. In practice -- no (due to NRVO). Therefore -- no UB. Hence, the "trick". I hoped there is a language construct that would make these tricks unnecessary. But, as I already suspected, there is no such thing.

Comment: @C.M.: Since it’s unspecified whether the copy/move that would have undefined behavior occurs, the behavior **is** undefined—even if you check addresses of your objects to try to reassure yourself, you can’t prove that the answer isn’t fabricated *by* the UB.

Comment: @DavisHerring In general case, yes. In practice (on practically all compilers) -- no (since none of them use `trap representation`. I understand your point, though. In fact, this raises another question -- maybe types that can have indeterminate values shouldn't have auto-generated default ctors and mtors? Or should implementation be explicitly allowed to do so as long as it permits reading indeterminate value? Should this omission be classified as C++ standard defect?

Comment: @C.M.: I don’t know what you mean by “on practically all compilers[] no”.  Whether your program has undefined behavior is determined by the standard, not any one compiler (except insofar as *implementation-defined* behavior is relevant), and no amount of testing or assembly examination can rule it out (since whatever you find is of course one possible outcome *of* undefined behavior).  Maybe you can check the source of all *compilers* and see that no optimizer happens to make use of this leeway—today—but that seems a very poor guide!  As long as we can copy `int`s, this situation will pertain.

Comment: @DavisHerring I mean that for 99.99% compilers "reading indeterminate value" has defined behavior, namely "result value is indeterminate" and this value can be safely written to another location. Remaining 1 or 2 compilers where it isn't true are those used on very exotic hardware/OS -- where `trap representation` is used to catch access to indeterminate variables. I.e. while you are correct "in-principle", it has little value in practice.